# WPF PropertyPath on Custom control

Tags: wpf, animation, propertypath

I have a problem, I create a control named Tile (like the Tile on Windows 10).
This tile simulate rotation 3D by using a projection class, like the projection class in Silverlight.

We have a base projection class like this :

```
abstract public class Projection
    : FrameworkElement
{
    static public readonly DependencyProperty RotationZProperty = DependencyProperty.Register(
          nameof(RotationZ),
          typeof(double),
          typeof(Projection),
          new UIPropertyMetadata(0.0, OnRotationChanged));

    static public readonly DependencyProperty RotationYProperty = DependencyProperty.Register(
            nameof(RotationY),
            typeof(double),
            typeof(Projection),
            new UIPropertyMetadata(0.0, OnRotationChanged));

    static public readonly DependencyProperty RotationXProperty = DependencyProperty.Register(
            nameof(RotationX),
            typeof(double),
            typeof(Projection),
            new UIPropertyMetadata(0.0, OnRotationChanged));

public double RotationZ
{
    get { return this.GetValue<double>(RotationZProperty); }
    set { SetValue(RotationZProperty, value); }
}

public double RotationY
{
    get { return this.GetValue<double>(RotationYProperty); }
    set { SetValue(RotationYProperty, value); }
}

public double RotationX
{
    get { return this.GetValue<double>(RotationXProperty); }
    set { SetValue(RotationXProperty, value); }
}

public FrameworkElement Child
{
    get;
    set;
}

static private void OnRotationChanged(DependencyObject d, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            if (d is Projection pl)
            {
                pl.OnRotationChanged();
            }
        }

        private void OnRotationChanged()
        {
            // Some code
        }}

After that, we have the PlaneProjectionClass :

     [ContentProperty("Child")]
    sealed public class PlaneProjection
        : Projection
    {   
    }
```

The Tile class use a dependency property of type Projection :

```
     public class Tile
    {
     static public readonly DependencyProperty PlaneProjectionProperty = DependencyProperty.Register(
            nameof(Projection),
            typeof(Projection),
            typeof(Tile),
            new UIPropertyMetadata());

 public Projection Projection
        {
            get { return (Projection)GetValue(PlaneProjectionProperty); }
            private set { SetValue(PlaneProjectionProperty, value); }
        }

        override public void OnApplyTemplate()
        {
            Projection = GetTemplateChild("PART_Projection") as Projection;
        }
     }
```

So for the XAML, we have this in ControlTemplate :

```
    <controls:PlaneProjection x:Name="PART_PlaneProjection">
    <Border>
    <Grid>
      <!-- Some design -->
    </Grid>
    </Border>
</controls:PlaneProjection>
```

Now I would like to animate the planeprojection.

So I create the storyboard and animate the projection with rotationX :

```
static public void CreateAnimation(Tile tile)
{
    Storyboard.SetTarget(anim, tile);
    Storyboard.SetTargetProperty(doubleAnim, new PropertyPath("(Tile.Projection).(PlaneProjection.RotationX"));
 }
```

But at debug, I have this error : Cannot resolve all references of the property on the path of the property '(Tile.Projection).(PlaneProjection.RotationX)

I don't understand the mistake :( Any ideas on using PropertyPath on custom control ?

Answer (score 3):

The `Projection` property in class Tile does not follow the naming conventions for dependency properties.

It should e.g. look like this:

```
public static readonly DependencyProperty PlaneProjectionProperty =
    DependencyProperty.Register(nameof(PlaneProjection), typeof(Projection), typeof(Tile));

public Projection PlaneProjection
{
    get { return (Projection)GetValue(PlaneProjectionProperty); }
    private set { SetValue(PlaneProjectionProperty, value); }
}
```

The property path would simply be this:

```
Storyboard.SetTargetProperty(anim, new PropertyPath("PlaneProjection.RotationX"));
```

You wouldn't even need a Storyboard. Just call

```
tile.PlaneProjection.BeginAnimation(Projection.RotationXProperty, anim);
```

---

As a note, a private setter does not make the dependency property read-only. See [Read-Only Dependency Properties](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wpf/advanced/read-only-dependency-properties) for details.